# Making functions from an emacs mode available outside the mode's file

Tags: function, export, elisp

I've written an emacs minor mode that should make some functions available for explicit invocation in addition to the minor mode. In the mode's file, after defining the modes and the function, I've `provide`d the mode:

```
(provide 'xcode-dired-mode)
```

which, in my `.emacs` I `require`:

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/Documents/Local Projects/xcode-emacs" load-path))
(require 'xcode-dired-mode "xcode-dired")
```

Now when a buffer is in this mode, I want to have a few extra functions available. If I `defun` a function in the lisp file for the minor mode, like:

```
(defun xcode-build()
  "Build the default target in the Xcode project."
  ;; ...
  )
```

the functions are not available outside the file, e.g. `M-x xcode-build` will not work. I don't think `provide`ing the files is the appropriate thing to do, as I don't want to have to `require` all of them in `.emacs`. I've seen the magic comment `;;; ###autoload` but as far as I can tell that's only used when compiling emacs itself.

How do I arrange that when my minor mode is applied to a buffer, the functions defined in the mode's lisp file can be used?

Comment: For added clarification to the accepted answer: As soon as a file has been loaded (by `require` in this instance), all of the defined functions, variables, etc defined by that file are available to code outside of that file.

Comment: Note that `;;;###autoload` comments will also be used by various package managers (`el-get` is one example; I presume `package.el` also uses them). So if you are writing code for use by other people, you should prepend those autoload comments to the appropriate definitions so that anyone using your code via one of those package managers does not need to add their own autoload configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call `xcode-build` via `M-x`, you'll need to make sure the function implementation calls the `interactive` special-form to declare the function as interactively callable.

I believe this is the relevant emacs documentation:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html